# Angular 1 service - RxJS share operator not working properly

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, angularjs-service, rxjs5

I have created a service that uses `RxJS` to wrap `$http` calls.

I have several components subscribing to the same observable and I want them to share the AJAX result instead of making multiple requests.

**Service code:**

```
export function SearchService($http) {
    'ngInject';

    const autocompleteResults$ = new Subject()
        .debounceTime(250)
        .switchMap(query => Observable.fromPromise($http.post('/search', { query })))
        .share()
        .map(result => result.data);


    function autocomplete(query) {
        autocompleteResults$.next(query);
    }

    return {
        autocomplete,
        autocompleteResults$
    };
}
```

**Component code:**

```
export const myComponent = {
    bindings: {
        query: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: templateUrl,
    controller: myController
};

function myController($SearchService) {
    'ngInject';
    const $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.$onInit = $onInit;
    $ctrl.$onChanges = $onChanges;

    function $onInit() {
        SearchService.autocompleteResults$
            .subscribe(
                handleSuccess,
                handleError
            );
    }

    function $onChanges(changes) {
        if (changes.query && changes.query.currentValue)
            SearchService.autocomplete(changes.query.currentValue);
    }
}
```

I have **2** active components of `myComponent` that respond to the query changes.

Since `Angular` services are singletons, each component should get the same observable instance when subscribing to it, but there are always 2 AJAX calls instead of 1.

I tried using the `share`, `publish`, `publishReplay`, `shareReplay` and `refCount` operators with no success.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe seems more like you're looking for caching instead of sharing and Observable.

When you use `share()` you're just sharing the same subscription to its source Observable but not its result.

For example if an HTTP requests takes 100ms then this will make two requests even when using `share()`:

```
const source = this.http.get(...).share();
source.subscribe(...);

setTimeout(() => source.subscribe(...), 1000);
```

The `share()` operator doesn't help you here at all because after the first HTTP request is done the observer unsubscribes and the Subject inside `share()` unsubscribes as well. Then after 1s you make another subscription and it needs to resubscribe again which makes another HTTP requests.

However, if you did the following then you'll make just one HTTP requests:

```
const source = this.http.get(...).share();
source.subscribe(...);
source.subscribe(...);
```

When the second observer subscribes the first one is still active and is multicasted via `share()`. Thus you'll make just one HTTP call.

Maybe you're looking for something like this that replays a received value for 1s:

```
const source = this.http.get(...)
    .publishReplay(1, 1000)
    .refCount()
    .take(1);
```